# Amazon Athena error opening Hive split s3 path and Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I'm query data from glue catalog. For some of table I can see the data and some of table getting below error:

> Error opening Hive split s3://test/sample/run-1-part-r-03 (offset=0, length=1156) using org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat: Permission denied on S3 path: s3://test/sample/run-1-part-r-03

I have give full access to Athena.

Comment: The error is saying that it could not access an object in a bucket called `test`. Are you actually attempting to access that data in a bucket called `test`, or did you change the URL before putting the error here in StackOverflow?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Athena adopts the permissions from the user when accessing Amazon S3.

If the user can access the objects in Amazon S3, then they can access them via Amazon Athena.

Does the user who ran the command have access to those objects?

Comment: Hi John I resolved the issue as i didnt gave permission/Register the S3 location on lake formation.Now i can able to access the data.Thank you

Comment: @ParagShahade same here.  Lake Formation registration was the final piece!